# MySQL possible to update multiple rows with different where clause, single query

Tags: c#, mysql

Is is possible to have one query update multiple columns with different where clauses
for example, can you combine this?

update tblTest set price = '5000' where id = '2'

update tblTest set price = '3000' where id = '3'

update tblTest set price = '4000' where id = '4'

how would you combine those 3 queries to one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's

```
UPDATE `tblTest` SET `price` = CASE `Id` 
    WHEN 2 THEN 5000
    WHEN 3 THEN 3000
    WHEN 4 THEN 4000
END CASE;
```